# Ajax Path not working, can't find the cause

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple Ajax function that changes a div.
The following code works, but it loads the **index.php** in my div also, which I don't want.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?p=productDesc&q="+currentID,true);
```

Although the above works I'm trying to take the **productDesc.php** only, and it does not work.

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","pages/productDesc&q="+currentID,true);
```

Any ideas what might be causing that?
I searched but according to what I found I don't have anything wrong.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: You forgot `.php` and `?` at the end. It should be `xmlhttp.open("GET","pages/productDesc.php?q="+currentID,true);`

Comment: And make sure that `productDesc.php` really exists.

Comment: "Does not work" is not an adequate error description. Please be more elaborate on the expected behaviour and your specific problem.

Comment: where are you making the request from? You are using relative path and if that path isn't valid in same directory page is in you need to use absolute path

Comment: Guys thank you everyone for your answers, actually  Rajdeep Paul was right.
I will try to be more specific next time.

Comment: @TasosAnesiadis learn to use broser dev tools ... network tab would have shown 404 not found status, and the actual url that was used among many other parts of the request as well

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will keep it in mind!